# Dataframe selecting Max for a column but output values of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with values similar to below

```
A10d  B10d  C10d  A   B   C   Strategy
20    10    5     3   5   1    3
```

The Strategy selects the max of A10d, B10d, C10d and return the value of A,B,C
In this case A10d is the largest and Strategy returns A, value of 3

I am not sure how to create this Strategy column properly, can anyone advise please? Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first columns by positions and then get columns names by `max` with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `10d` by whitespace for match columns. Last create new column by [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
print (df)
   A10d  B10d  C10d  A  B  C
0    20    10     5  3  5  1
1    20   100     5  3  5  1

df1 = df.iloc[:,:3]
print (df1)
   A10d  B10d  C10d
0    20    10     5
1    20   100     5

s = df1.idxmax(axis=1).str.replace('10d','')
print (s)
0    A
1    B
dtype: object

df['Strategy'] = df.lookup(df.index, s)
print (df)
   A10d  B10d  C10d  A  B  C  Strategy
0    20    10     5  3  5  1         3
1    20   100     5  3  5  1         5
```

Comment: Thank you Jezrael this works well, you saved my day again :)